# relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-keys, try-catch, dbcontext

i have a `gridview` .this grid view contains a lot of record (The member information) .

```
   try
            {
                Member member=new Member();
                IdMember = int.Parse(gvListCompany.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString());


                member = objMemberRepository.FindBy(i => i.Id == IdMember).First();
                objMemberRepository.Delete(member);
                objMemberRepository.Save();


                toolStripStatusLabelLine.Visible = true;
                lblState.Text = "delete is successfully";
                StatusMain.BackColor = Color.Green;

                gvListCompany.DataSource = objMemberRepository.FindBy(i => i.IsSupporter == typeofmember).ToList();
            }
            catch
            {
                toolStripStatusLabelLine.Visible = true;
                lblState.Text = "couldn't delete because of subset records";
                StatusMain.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#ea0000");
                return;

            }
```

Here is a code to delete an item of the grid view .Suppose i want to delete a record that has an `FK item` in another table so the records can't be deleted and the try statement throw an exception and i show the proper `error` to user like `this record has an subset please delete the subset` after this operation if i try to delete a record that doesn't have any `FK` in other table i got the same error and i can't delete that but in fact i should be able to delete because my record doesn't have any `FK` records in other table .

Error message

```
The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.
```

Member class:

```
   public partial class Member
    {
        public Member()
        {
            this.Inovices = new HashSet<Inovice>();
        }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; 
        public string EconomicCompnayNumber { get; set; }
        public string IntNumber { get; set; }
        public string Province { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string PostCode { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public string Region { get; set; }
        public string IsSupporter { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Inovice> Inovices { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Cash> Cashes { get; set; }
}
```

I changed my code to this and it works ,but i really don't know why ?

```
    MemberRepository aa = new MemberRepository();

    Member member=new Member();
        IdMember = int.Parse(gvListCompany.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString());

        Name = gvListCompany.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        member = aa.FindBy(i => i.Id == IdMember).First();
    try
    {


        aa.Delete(member);
        aa.Save();


        toolStripStatusLabelLine.Visible = true;
        lblState.Text = "شرکت  " + Name + " با موفقیت حذف شد ";
        StatusMain.BackColor = Color.Green;

        gvListCompany.DataSource = aa.FindBy(i => i.IsSupporter == typeofmember).ToList();
    }
    catch
    {
        toolStripStatusLabelLine.Visible = true;
        lblState.Text = "برای '" + Name + "' در سیستم فاکتور ثبت شده است ";
        StatusMain.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#ea0000");
        return;

    }
```

I think it because of dbcontext .

Best regards

Comment: Your try/catch is rather overzealous. ANYTHING that goes wrong inside of that try block will report that it failed with "couldn't delete because of subset records". Let the exception get thrown (inside of catch, just put "throw;" on a line) so you can see what the actual problem is.

Comment: Could you please tell me where exactly should put the throw statement ?

Comment: Inside of the catch{} block. Ideally, your try{} statement should contain just the .Delete() and .Save() methods so that your catch{} will be limited in scope to the code that you are actually attempting to catch.
catch
{
 throw;
 //...
}

This doesn't seem to be the actual issue you are experiencing (based on your update with an actual error), but I'd recommend it anyway.

Comment: I put the save and delete method in try statement but the same error

Comment: My problem is solved by insert repository class inside the try/catch ,i mean i create a new repository and it works but why ??            MemberRepository aa = new MemberRepository();